# Walk through recursive array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

is there a way to go through an recursive array?

`$GLOBALS` looks like this:

```
array(7) {
  ["_GET"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  ["_POST"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
 ["_COOKIE"]=>
    array(1) {
    ["PHPSESSID"]=>
    string(26) "n02ngn8h62sbtm4kgijdp5pnc1"
 }
 ["_FILES"]=>
   array(0) {
   }
 ["GLOBALS"]=>
   *RECURSION*
   ["format"]=>
   object(Format)#1 (0) {
   }
   ["test"]=>
   object(Test)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

I'd like to have an output like `[format] => object(format), [test] => object(test)`

Any Ideas?
Philip

Comment: [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: this looks so complicated, i guessed there was a simpler way?

Comment: It's difficult to say what it looks like (complicated or otherwise) because you don't really explain exactly what it is that you want

Comment: when I do: `foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) { echo $key."<br>"; }` I get in return: 

`_GET`
`_POST`
`_COOKIE`
`_FILES`
`GLOBALS`
`format`
`test`

I only want to get `format` and `test`

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the key and ignore all keys that start with an underscore or the word globals?`if ((substr($key,0,1) != '_') AND ($key != 'GLOBALS')) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Then just filter to get the values you want

```
$filter = array('format', 'test');
foreach (array_intersect_key($GLOBALS, array_flip($filter)) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."<br>";
}
```